# Ctrl+T doesn't create a new tab anymore

Tags: gnome, keyboard, shortcut-keys

Pretty new to Ubuntu, I tried to change some keyboard shortcut.

So I assigned under the System > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to an operation.

Then I realised that with chrome <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> was not opening me a new tab but doing the operation configured earlier. Now I can't make <kbd>Ctr</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> create a new tab on Chrome.

Someone does know how can I put it back please?

Ps. I am on Gnome

Comment: Have you tried to delete the keyboard shortcut that you have newly created?.

Comment: I did but  nothing changed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to

> System > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts

select the command to which you assigned <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and press <kbd>Backspace</kbd>.

This will remove the *CTRL+T* keyboard shortcut and you'll be able to use *CTRL+T* as before in Chrome.

Comment: Maybe a restart of Chrome will be needed too.

Comment: Just did it. So now no Shortcut is assigned to Ctrl+T but the new tab is not back to chrome. Any idea ?

Comment: Can you use CTRL+T to open a tab in another application (for example in the Gedit text editor)?

Comment: I just rebooted the whole computer it did work now. Thanks for the help !

Comment: Then please mark the question as answered :)